# I used apt-get to install firefox in ubuntu touch and can't run it

Tags: unity, firefox, ubuntu-touch

I've tried firefox and /usr/bin/firefox and I get the same error message.

```
(process:5119):GLib-CRITICAL **:g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
error: no display specified
```

so I ran

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

the error read

```
(process:5719):GLib-CRITICAL **:g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
cannot open display: :0
```

I know just enough to get myself I trouble but not enough to solve this issue for myself yet.

Any constructive suggestions?

Comment: From where do you try to run firefox? From a shell or from the launcher? Don't you have an icon in the menu after the installtion?

Comment: Not a constructive suggestion, but isn't XMir needed somehow?